# Automatically Hide empty collections in navigation on Shopify Impulse Theme

Tags: shopify, themes, liquid

I would like to automatically hide empty collections in Shopify Impluse theme.

Here is the code, but I can't work out how get the amount of products in the collection.

```
                  {%- for grandchildlink in childlink.links -%}  
                    <div>
                      <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}" class="site-nav__dropdown-link">
                        {{grandchildlink.title}}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  {%- endfor -%}
                {%- endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you browse a link object, you can access object attributes related to the link.

So you might write something like this:

```
{%- for grandchildlink in childlink.links -%}
    {% unless grandchildlink.object.all_products_count < 1 %}
        Do something
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation available here: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#link-object